# Laravel 5.5 retrieving null by nested relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 3 databases:

Routes:

`id
name`

Rates:

```
Id
Route_id
Car_id
```

Cars:

```
id
name
```

My model for routes

```
public function rates()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Rate', 'route_id');
}
```

My model for rates

```
public function car() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Car','car_id');
}
```

Now I need to access the car relation, but when I do

```
return $this->route->with('from','to','rates.car')->paginate(74);
```

I get null for the car relation

```
{"id":1,"from_id":1,"to_id":2,"distance":400,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"from":{"id":1,"name":"\u0410\u043a\u043a\u043e","created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"lat":32.93310000000000314912540488876402378082275390625,"long":35.0827000000000026602720026858150959014892578125},"to":{"id":2,"name":"\u0410\u0440\u0430\u0434","created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"lat":31.261399999999998300381776061840355396270751953125,"long":35.21490000000000009094947017729282379150390625},"rates":[{"id":1,"route_id":1,"car_id":1,"rate":1123,"night_rate":1391,"car":null},{"id":5551,"route_id":1,"car_id":2,"rate":1123,"night_rate":1391,"car":null},{"id":11101,"route_id":1,"car_id":3,"rate":1123,"night_rate":1391,"car":null},{"id":16651,"route_id":1,"car_id":4,"rate":1123,"night_rate":1391,"car":null},{"id":22201,"route_id":1,"car_id":5,"rate":1123,"night_rate":1391,"car":null},{"id":27751,"route_id":1,"car_id":6,"rate":1123,"night_rate":1391,"car":null},{"id":33301,"route_id":1,"car_id":7,"rate":1123,"night_rate":1391,"car":null},{"id":38851,"route_id":1,"car_id":8,"rate":1123,"night_rate":1391,"car":null}]},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding you are trying to access a Car model through a Route model.

A couple of things I noticed that should help you find a solution.

First off I think the inverse relation you are supposed to use the `belongToMany()` function instead.

```
public function car() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Car','Rates'); // Perhaps call the table something like routes_cars to more clearly define it's a pivot table
}
```

Next I see you are trying to use model functions within the context of `$this()`. I assume you are doing this in your model? That logic should be in a controller, that might cause some undesired results but I'm not entirely sure. Also it looks like your parameters are incorrect when using `with()`.  You use the function name that you defined in `belongsToMany()`

```
App/Route::with('car')->paginate(74);
```

With the correct relationships setup you rarely need to worry about the pivot table. If you are going to add extra information in the pivot table there are laravel functions to help you do that in the documentation.

Comment: $this->route is used in a controller with a construct function.

Comment: And Rates is not used as a pivot table, there’re two columns I forgot to write rate and night_rate. But I want to access it nested, so I could get the car name like this in car:{id:1, name:’economy ‘}. I showed an example

Comment: It is a pivot table because it creates a relationship between two other tables. 
 They can contain other data. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships.  Search for `Retrieving Intermediate Table Columns`.